# Understanding one to many relationships in flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to learn relationships in flask_sqlalchemy but having really hard time to get the code working. Firstly there is lack of good tutorials on this topic, but still I joined bits and pieces of information to write some code but I am not getting the expected results.

Can you explain what I'm doing wrong in this code?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://<my_user>:<my_password>@localhost/flask_apps'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Universe(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'universe'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30))
    hero = db.relationship('Characters', backref='u_name', lazy='dynamic')


class Characters(db.Model):
    __tablename__= 'characters'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    uni = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('universe.id'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
    dc = Universe(name='DC')
    marvel = Universe(name='Marvel')
    db.session.add(dc)
    db.session.add(marvel)
    db.session.commit()
    flash = Characters(name='Flash', u_name=dc)
    batman = Characters(name='Batman', u_name=dc)
    arrow = Characters(name='Arrow', u_name=dc)
    ironman = Characters(name='IronMan', u_name=marvel)
    thor = Characters(name='Thor', u_name=marvel)
    db.session.add(flash)
    db.session.add(ironman)
    db.session.commit()

    u = Universe.query.filter_by(name='DC').first()
    print(u.hero)
```

And this is the output I am getting.

```
SELECT characters.id AS characters_id, characters.name AS characters_name, characters.uni AS characters_uni 
FROM characters 
WHERE %(param_1)s = characters.uni

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am expecting to get the character names who belong that particular universe. Not really sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this, the issue was the misinterpretation of `hero` as a single valued attribute which instead is a collection. So using the below query works.

```
u = Universe.query.filter_by(name='DC').first()
    for item in u.hero[:]:
        print(item.name)
```